# How is schema linked to a Model in DXA+Java MVP Implementation?

Tags: 2013-sp1, schema, dxa, java, mvc

I am new to java and was trying to write a model for a schema. I want to understand how a schema is linked with the model.

For e.g. I have schema with below details:

1. heading (Text Field) - Single value
2. menuLink (Embedded schema) - Multi value

[The embeded schema used here is 'link' which contains fields for creating a external or Tridion link]

When I write a model based on schema field names , it is something like

```
private String headline;
private List<Link> menuLink;
```

I also generate the getters and setters.
I am able to display headline in my view, but not able to display any value from embedded fields i.e. menuLink

If I change this to:

```
private String headline;
//Changed to menuLinks instead of menuLink
private List<Link> menuLinks;
```

and generate getters and setters. This works fine with views.

The question here is why we need to use '**menuLinks**' instead of '**menuLink**' in the model even when the field name is menuLink? Is it because it is a multivalue field? How is this mapping done?

Also which datatype should be used for check-box while writing a model?

p.s. I do not have any guidelines for java MVC, so maybe I have missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Tridion Reference Implementation (aka DXA) documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Reference%20Implementation-v1/GUID-2BED2168-26D2-465E-92D8-68C3D5219088), when default semantic mapping is used the naming convention of multi-value fields is defined as follows:

> When attempting to populate a property of type List, remove any
>   trailing s's from the property name. For example, the Paragraphs
>   property is mapped to Schema field paragraph.

Meaning DXA by convention assumes properties in the Model to be named plural (ending with 's') for multi-value Schema fields.

Comment: Interesting and thanks for answering, Jeroen. I often see plural names on the Tridion-side for Schemas. Though technically, if you look at the XML, multi-value Schema fields should be singular, right? We get `<menuLink/><menuLink/>` rather than `<menuLinks><menuLink/>...</menuLinks>`.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. Still trying to understand the semantics concept though ; Wonder how would it work for a field name ending with s. For e.g. if field name is class? Also how can write a model for checkbox?

Comment: In the case of a multivalue field class DXA will strip the last 's' off so that would turn a bit ugly. In that case I would recommend using a semantic mapping, for instance:
'[SemanticProperty("class")]
public List<MyClass> classList;'

Comment: To model a checkbox in Tridion you would model a text field in the Schema with 'Values will be Selected from a List' using 'List type' is 'Check boxes', which means a property of type String in your model.

Comment: Thanks, I tried hard but couldn't use checkbox. Strangely dropdown was working. So using dropdown as of now.